# Create a grid array

Tags: c++, arrays, grid, multidimensional-array, ogre3d

I created a grid array in OGRE3D game engine but the array is generic my array skills are pretty basic and need work so I am posting this just to be sure I am doing this correctly.

```
#define GRIDWIDTH 10
#define GRIDHEIGHT 10

int myGrid [HEIGHT][WIDTH];
int n,m;

int main ()
{
  for (n=0;n<HEIGHT;n++)
    for (m=0;m<WIDTH;m++)
    {
      jimmy[n][m]=(n+1)*(m+1);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

I am assuming the above will return:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Then I can assign each point in the array to a valid node in OGRE3D to create a grid in 3D view would this work? Just need to tell me if I am doing it right or wrong dont need the ogre3d code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is going to be filled with a multiplication lookup chart with that code:

```
  1  2  3  4  
1 1  2  3  4   
2 2  4  6  8  
3 6  9 12 15  
4 8 12 16 20
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: ahh i see, what I want is:

  for (n=0;n<HEIGHT;n++)
    for (m=0;m<WIDTH;m++)
    {
      myGrid[n][m]= x and y values that refer to array position;
    }
  return 0;

so if array position is myGrid[1][2] x=1 and y=2

Comment: Okay so what I wanted is an multidimensional array, it will create a new node based on its n and m position in the array so it will be as simple as (n + m) * 10, * 10 because I want to create a decent amount of space between each node, those this sound valid to you?

Comment: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=57328&p=387482#p387482 the exact solution to my exact problem can be found here